# logic question on placing two items in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, image, for-loop, logic

this is a logic question, im programming in javascript:

scenario: i have a database that holds 20 images, and im going through all of them one by one using a for loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

//logic

}
```

what im trying to do for every two images retrieved add them to 1 row

2 image = 1 row

and the next 2 images put them in one and so on and so forth.....

but i dont understand how i could this, espcially when one image is being retrieved at one timee each.. i hope you can help me thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to print an image on every loop round, when i is 2,4,6,8... You need to add line break. If using HTML this would be `<br>`.

You should do this by putting an if block.

If i % 2 = 0 then
   Line break 
End if

The % is the modulus operator, it tests for the remainder of i/2 which will be 0 if an even number.

Comment: Thanks @Matt it's hard doing the code examples from the iPhone :-)

Comment: It's even harder posting a detailed answer when there's a new answer every 10 seconds ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

//logic for retrieving and placing image 2 * i in row i
//logic for retrieving and placing image 2 * i + 1 in row i

}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer i don't really get what you mean here? :)) im so stupid sometimes

Comment: no worries.  by looping over 10 (number of rows) instead of 20 (number of images), you can then match rows to images more simply.  if that's not addressing your problem, try expanding on where exactly you are having trouble with your code...

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    code += '<img src="' + images[i] + '">' + (i % 2 ? '<br>' : '');
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/7yDJv/